# How to do WHERE x IN (val1, val2,...) in plpgsql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, array

I would like to update a selection of rows in a table; this works...

```
UPDATE t1 SET col1 = 'newvalue' WHERE col0 in (2, 4, 5);
```

But how can I do the same in a plpgsql function? The following gives a syntax error...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(intarray int[])
RETURNS VOID AS 
$BODY$

BEGIN
  UPDATE t1 SET col1 = 'newvalue'
  WHERE col0 in intarray;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

The error...

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "intarray"
LINE 7:       WHERE col0 in intarray;
```

**Edit:**

If we replace `in intarray;` with `in (intarray);` the function is recorded but when running `SELECT * FROM foo(ARRAY[1,3,5])` the error becomes...

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer = integer[]
LINE 2:       WHERE col0 in (intarray)
```

Comment: Add your error message?

Comment: Shoudnt that be in_array instead of intarray?

Comment: intarray is the variable name of the array passed in the function.

Comment: `WHERE col0 = ANY (intarray) `

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name , that works! thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[@a_horse already pointed out](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61520/how-to-do-where-x-in-val1-val2-in-plpgsql#comment110662_61520): to use `x = ANY (array_value)` instead of `x IN (set of values)`. Read [the manual about `ANY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-comparisons.html#AEN18486).

With long arrays (100+ elements, it depends), it is faster to `unnest()` and join. 
And it may be more convenient to use a `VARIADIC` function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(VARIADIC intarray int[])
  RETURNS void AS 
$func$
BEGIN
  UPDATE t1
  SET    col1 = 'newvalue'
  FROM   unnest (intarray) a(elem)
  WHERE  t1.col0 = a.elem;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then you can call the function as:

```
SELECT foo(1,2,3);
```

But you can still hand in a whole array, too:

```
SELECT foo(VARIADIC intarray := '{1,2,3}');
```

Details in the manual [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html) and [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-VARIADIC-FUNCTIONS).

Answer (score 6):

`IN (...)` expects a literal list of values.

If you write `x IN (some_array)` then PostgreSQL expects `x` to also be an array, since you're testing to see whether the array `x` appears in the one-element list of arrays `(some_array)`.

If you instead want to see if the value `x` appears as an element of the array `some_array` you must write:

```
x = ANY (some_array)
```

(Note that you can use `ANY` with pretty much any operator, not just `=`, and that there's an `ALL` as well as an `ANY`.)