# CTE works as expected, but not when wrapped into a function

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql, cte

```
--testing table
CREATE TABLE public.test_patient_table (
                entity_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                site_held_at INTEGER NOT NULL,
                CONSTRAINT entityid_pk PRIMARY KEY (entity_id)
);

CREATE TABLE public.test_messageq_table (
                entity_id VARCHAR NOT NULL,
                master_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                message_body VARCHAR NOT NULL,
                CONSTRAINT mq_entity_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (entity_id)
);

CREATE INDEX test_patient_table_siteid_idx
 ON public.test_patient_table
 ( site_held_at );

ALTER TABLE public.test_messageq_table
ADD CONSTRAINT test_patient_table_test_messageq_table_fk
FOREIGN KEY (master_id)
REFERENCES public.test_patient_table (entity_id)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION
NOT DEFERRABLE;

--test patient data
insert into test_patient_table values (1, 11111);
insert into test_patient_table values (2, 11111);
insert into test_patient_table values (3, 11111);
insert into test_patient_table values (4, 11111);

insert into test_patient_table values (5, 22222);
insert into test_patient_table values (6, 22222);
insert into test_patient_table values (7, 22222);
insert into test_patient_table values (8, 22222);

insert into test_patient_table values (9, 33333);
insert into test_patient_table values (10, 33333);

insert into test_patient_table values (11, 44444);

--testing message
insert into test_messageq_table values (1, 1, 'aaa');
insert into test_messageq_table values (2, 1, 'aaa');
insert into test_messageq_table values (3, 1, 'aaa');
insert into test_messageq_table values (4, 1, 'aaa');
insert into test_messageq_table values (5, 2, 'aaa');
insert into test_messageq_table values (6, 2, 'aaa');
insert into test_messageq_table values (7, 5, 'aaa');
insert into test_messageq_table values (8, 8, 'aaa');
insert into test_messageq_table values (9, 11, 'aaa');
insert into test_messageq_table values (10, 11, 'bbb');
```

When I tried to find all messages from message table in site I am interested, I wrote a CTE and it works fine, let's say I am interested in site 11111 and 22222:

```
WITH patient_msg_in_branches AS (
    select distinct test_messageq_table.master_id AS patient_id,
    test_patient_table.site_held_at as site_id
    from test_messageq_table 
    inner join test_patient_table 
    ON test_messageq_table.master_id = test_patient_table.entity_id 
    and site_held_at in (11111,22222) order by patient_id
),
messages_for_patients AS(
    select * from test_messageq_table where master_id in 
        (select patient_msg_in_branches.patient_id 
            from patient_msg_in_branches)
)select * from messages_for_patients
```

The result is as expected:

```
"1";1;"aaa"
"2";1;"aaa"
"3";1;"aaa"
"4";1;"aaa"
"5";2;"aaa"
"6";2;"aaa"
"7";5;"aaa"
"8";8;"aaa"
```

But when I wrap the whole thing in a function, it's returning the wrong rows. Can you help me see why?

```
drop function getMessageFromSites(text);
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getMessageFromSites(IN ids TEXT) RETURNS 
setof test_messageq_table AS $$ 
DECLARE
       sites INT[];
       result test_messageq_table%rowtype;

BEGIN
       sites = string_to_array(ids,',');
        raise info 'entire array: %', sites;

WITH patient_msg_in_branches AS (
    select distinct test_messageq_table.master_id AS patient_id,
    test_patient_table.site_held_at as site_id
    from test_messageq_table 
    inner join test_patient_table 
    ON test_messageq_table.master_id = test_patient_table.entity_id 
    and site_held_at = ANY(sites) order by patient_id
),
messages_for_patients AS(
    select * from test_messageq_table where master_id in 
        (select patient_msg_in_branches.patient_id 
            from patient_msg_in_branches)
)select * into result from messages_for_patients;
return query select * from result;
END;     
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When using the function:

```
select * from getMessageFromSites('11111,22222');
select * from getMessageFromSites('1')
select * from getMessageFromSites('33333')
```

it always returns the same result **below** of multiple rows but obviously wrong rows, why ? can you help here ?

```
"1";1;"aaa"
"2";1;"aaa"
"3";1;"aaa"
"4";1;"aaa"
"5";2;"aaa"
"6";2;"aaa"
"9";11;"aaa"
"10";11;"bbb"
```

### Solution

Thanks to @a_horse_with_no_name, now I have two working solutions, one with sql, one with pl/pgsql:

#### Solution 1 (pl/pgsql)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getMessageFromSites(IN ids TEXT) RETURNS 
setof test_messageq_table AS $$ 
DECLARE
       sites INT[];
       result test_messageq_table%rowtype;

BEGIN
       sites = string_to_array(ids,',');
       raise info 'entire array: %', sites;
 return QUERY

    WITH patient_msg_in_branches AS (
        select distinct test_messageq_table.master_id AS patient_id,
        test_patient_table.site_held_at as site_id
        from test_messageq_table 
        inner join test_patient_table 
        ON test_messageq_table.master_id = test_patient_table.entity_id 
        and site_held_at = ANY(sites) order by patient_id
    ),
    messages_for_patients AS(
        select * from test_messageq_table where master_id in 
            (select patient_msg_in_branches.patient_id 
                from patient_msg_in_branches)
    )
    select * from messages_for_patients;

END;     
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

#### Solution 2 (sql)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getMessageFromSites2(ids TEXT) RETURNS 
   setof test_messageq_table 
AS 
$$ 
  WITH patient_msg_in_branches AS (
      select distinct test_messageq_table.master_id AS patient_id,
             test_patient_table.site_held_at as site_id
      from test_messageq_table 
      join test_patient_table ON test_messageq_table.master_id = test_patient_table.entity_id 
                                and site_held_at = ANY (string_to_array($1,',')::int[]) 
  ),
  messages_for_patients AS
  (
    select * 
    from test_messageq_table 
    where master_id in (select patient_msg_in_branches.patient_id 
                        from patient_msg_in_branches)
  )
  select * 
  from messages_for_patients;
$$ 
LANGUAGE sql;
```

Testing of the code

```
select * from getMessageFromSites('11111,44444');
select * from getMessageFromSites('22222');
select * from getMessageFromSites('1')
select * from getMessageFromSites('33333')

select * from getMessageFromSites2('11111');
select * from getMessageFromSites2('22222');
select * from getMessageFromSites2('33333');
select * from getMessageFromSites('44444,11111');
select * from getMessageFromSites('1');
```

Both PG stored procedure are working as expected!

Solution 3:
A better simplified solution see from Erwin's answer below.

Now case closed !

Comment: That's a function not an SP

Comment: @JamesAnderson: Postgres doesn't have real stored procedures. So in the Postgres world the term "procedure" is often used as a synonym for "function"

Comment: Ah didn't see the Postgres tag. My mistake

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this is because you only ever return the first row from the query's result.

The `select ... into ...` will only retrieve one row and the `query select * from result` returns only that single record:

You also don't need a PL/pgSQL function, a plain SQL function will work just fine:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getMessageFromSites(ids TEXT) RETURNS 
   setof test_messageq_table 
AS 
$$ 
  WITH patient_msg_in_branches AS (
      select distinct test_messageq_table.master_id AS patient_id,
             test_patient_table.site_held_at as site_id
      from test_messageq_table 
         join test_patient_table ON test_messageq_table.master_id = test_patient_table.entity_id 
                                and site_held_at = ANY (string_to_array(ids,',')::int[]) 
  ),
  messages_for_patients AS
  (
    select * 
    from test_messageq_table 
    where master_id in (select patient_msg_in_branches.patient_id 
                        from patient_msg_in_branches)
  )
  select * 
  from messages_for_patients;
$$ 
LANGUAGE sql;
```

Note that the order by inside the CTE is not really useful. You have to sort the final select, not the intermediate steps.

If you do need PL/pgSQL because you are doing more stuff in the function, you should simply change it to:

```
begin
  ....
  return query
    WITH patient_msg_in_branches AS (
        select distinct test_messageq_table.master_id AS patient_id,
        test_patient_table.site_held_at as site_id
        from test_messageq_table 
        inner join test_patient_table 
        ON test_messageq_table.master_id = test_patient_table.entity_id 
        and site_held_at = ANY(sites) order by patient_id
    ),
    messages_for_patients AS(
        select * from test_messageq_table where master_id in 
            (select patient_msg_in_branches.patient_id 
                from patient_msg_in_branches)
    )
    select * from messages_for_patients;
end;
```

Answer (score 6):

You wrote "case closed", but I'll reopen. There is just too much gone wrong ...

### Database design and test setting

```
CREATE TABLE patient (
   patient_id   int PRIMARY KEY
 , site_held_at int NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE messageq (
   messageq_id  varchar PRIMARY KEY  -- varchar ?!
 , patient_id   int NOT NULL REFERENCES patient
 , message_body varchar NOT NULL
);

CREATE INDEX patient_site_idx ON patient(site_held_at);
CREATE INDEX messageq_patient_id_idx ON patient(patient_id); -- !!

INSERT INTO patient VALUES
  (1, 11111)
, (2, 11111)
, (3, 11111)
, (4, 11111)
, (5, 22222)
, (6, 22222)
, (7, 22222)
, (8, 22222)
, (9, 33333)
, (10, 33333)
, (11, 44444);

INSERT INTO messageq VALUES
  ('m1', 1, 'aaa1')
, ('m2', 1, 'aaa2')
, ('m3', 1, 'aaa3')
, ('m4', 1, 'aaa4')
, ('m5', 2, 'aaa5')
, ('m6', 2, 'aaa6')
, ('m7', 5, 'aaa7')
, ('m8', 8, 'aaa8')
, ('m9', 11, 'aaa9')
, ('m10', 11, 'bbb10');
```

#### Major points

- Simplify names for better readability.
- Don't use non-descriptive column names like `entity_id`. Replaced with useful names.
- It's good practice to use the same name for columns with identical content. Using `patient_id` for the FK column in `messageq`.
- If you indeed have a `varchar` PK in your message queue, test with actual `varchar` values.
- Simplify `INSERT` statements.
- Add an **index on `messageq.patient_id`**. This is crucial for performance.

### Function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_get_msg_from_sites(VARIADIC _id int[])
  RETURNS SETOF messageq AS 
$func$ 
   SELECT m.*
   FROM   patient  p
   JOIN   messageq m USING (patient_id)
   WHERE  p.site_held_at = ANY($1)
$func$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Yes, that's all.
Call:

```
SELECT * FROM f_get_msg_from_sites(11111, 44444);
SELECT * FROM f_get_msg_from_sites(22222);
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/b72d6/1) <sub>(on pg9.2, pg9.3 is overloaded)</sub>

#### Major points

- No need for a CTE (or even two). That would be a waste of code and time here. A simple query with joins does the job.
- Using a [`VARIADIC`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-VARIADIC-FUNCTIONS) parameter for simpler calls (optional).
  Related:

  - [How to do WHERE x IN (val1, val2,...) in plpgsql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61520/how-to-do-where-x-in-val1-val2-in-plpgsql/61552#61552)
- If `(patient_id int, site_held_at)` is unique in table `patient`, you do not need `DISTINCT` in the query. Else add it.

Comment: Thanks Erwin for all those good points. But I have noticed when using JOIN USING, it shows me the distinct result as expected while when I use JOIN ON (   SELECT messageq.*
   FROM   patient  p
   JOIN messageq  on 
   messageq.patient_id = messageq.patient_id ). it show duplicated result over 110 record. Is this expected ? Both case without using DISTINCT with same data.

Comment: @Gob00st: Your JOIN condition is wrong, would have to be `SELECT m.* FROM patient p JOIN messageq m ON m.patient_id = p.patient_id ...`.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake !