# PostgresSQL dynamic execute with argument values in array

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, parameter

I'm wondering if this is possible in Postgres:

Best explained using a contrived example:

```
create or replace function test_function(filter_param1 varchar default null
                                       , filter_param2 varchar default null)
  returns integer as
$$ 
declare
  stmt text;
  args varchar[];
  wher varchar[];
  retid integer;
begin
  if filter_param1 is not null then 
    array_append(args, filter_param1);
    array_append(wher, 'parameter_name = $1');
  end if;
  if filter_param2 is not null then 
    array_append(args, filter_param2);
    array_append(wher, 'parameter_name = $2');
  end if;

  stmt := 'select id from mytable where ' || array_to_string(wher, ' or ');
  execute stmt into retid using args;

  return retid;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

In Python there is `*args` - perhaps PostgreSQL has a similar mechanism?

EDIT for Erwin Brandstetter questions:

- All `filter` parameters will be applied to different columns, but should be AND'ed.
- Returning `setof` makes much more sense here.
- All parameters can be of the same column type (ie. `varchar`).

Comment: No, `EXECUTE ... USING` can't take an array of arguments, because PostgreSQL arrays don't support hetrogenous types. They must be an array of a single concrete type, and the SQL might not have the same type for each parameter. It'd be useless except for very narrow use cases. Instead, `USING` would have to be able to take an anonymous record, like you create from a `ROW(...)` constructor ... which is probably possible, but not currently implemented.

Comment: It's best explained with an example **plus an actual explanation**. Do you intend to apply all parameters to the same column `parameter_name`? (That could be largely simplified.) Or are you really thinking of different columns? Do you want to return a single value or a set of values? A bunch of OR'd predicates typically return multiple rows, which does not fit your `RETURNS` clause.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Either way, that's **totally possible**, given that all your parameters are of the **same data type**.

[**`EXECUTE ... USING`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) happily takes an array, which is treated as a **single** argument. Access elements with array subscripts. Your original function adapted:

```
create or replace function test_function(_filter1 text = null
                                       , _filter2 text = null
                                       , OUT retid int)
  language plpgsql as
$func$
declare
   _args text[] := ARRAY[_filter1, _filter2];
   _wher text[];
begin
   if _filter1 is not null then 
      _wher := _wher || 'parameter_name = $1[1]'; -- note array subscript
   end if;

   if _filter2 is not null then 
      _wher := _wher || 'parameter_name = $1[2]'; -- assign the result!
   end if;
  
   IF _args  IS NULL         -- check whether all params are NULL
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'At least one parameter required!';
   END IF;

   execute 'select id from mytable where ' -- cover case with all params NULL
         || array_to_string(_wher, ' or ')
         || ' ORDER BY id LIMIT 1';   -- For a single value (???)
   into  retid
   using _args;
end
$func$;
```

This is just a proof of concept and needlessly complicated. It would be an interesting option for *actual* array input, for instance with a `VARIADIC` function. Example:

- [How to do WHERE x IN (val1, val2,...) in plpgsql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61520/how-to-do-where-x-in-val1-val2-in-plpgsql/61552#61552)

For the case at hand, **use instead:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_function(_filter1 text = null
                                       , _filter2 text = null)
  RETURNS SETOF int
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _wher text := concat_ws(' OR '
             , CASE WHEN _filter1 IS NOT NULL THEN 'parameter_name = $1' END
             , CASE WHEN _filter2 IS NOT NULL THEN 'parameter_name = $2' END);
BEGIN
   IF _wher = ''   -- check whether all params are NULL
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'At least one parameter required!';
   END IF;

   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE ' || _wher
   USING  $1, $2;
   -- USING  _filter1 , filter2; -- alternatively use func param names
END
$func$;
```

List all values that can possibly be referenced in the dynamic query in the `USING` clause in their order of appearance. If not all of them will be referenced in the dynamic query, there's no harm in that. But we need to keep **ordinal positions** intact.

Note in particular that **`$n`** *inside the dynamic query* references given values of the `USING` clause by ordinal number, while **`$n`** *in the `USING` clause* references function parameters. Same syntax, different scope!
In my example, I kept the order of parameters in the `USING` clause in sync with function parameters, for simplicity. But we could list values in the `USING` clause in any order so that, for instance, `$2` in the dynamic query points to `$1` at the 2nd position in the `USING` clause, which references the 1st function parameter.

This allows for *any* number of parameters with ***any* (heterogeneous) data types**.

Returning a set of integer in this example(**`RETURNS SETOF int`**), which better fits the example - using [**`RETURN QUERY EXECUTE`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#AEN58217) accordingly.

[**`concat_ws()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) is particularly handy to assemble a list of OR'ed or AND'ed predicates conditionally.

Comment: thanks - even better! interesting that pg doesn't complain about surplus arguments in the 2nd example - if one filter is specified.

Comment: @Richard: Arguments provided in the `USING` clause can be referenced 0-n times. It's not exactly the same concept as `*args` in python, it's actually more flexible.

Answer (score -2):

```
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE SELECT
        TotalBookingAmount,
        TotalQuantity,
        TotalActualWeight,
        TotalChargedWeight,
        TotalLR,
        TotalDeliveryAmount,
        GrandTotalAmount,
        waybilltypeid,
        bookingmonth,
        bookingyear,
        sourcebranchid, 
        destinationbranchid 
                FROM '|| tableName || '
            where 
                accountgroupid          = ' || accountGropIdCol     :: numeric || '
            AND sourcebranchid          = ' || SourceBranchIdCol    :: numeric || '
            AND bookingmonth            = ' || bookingMonthCol      :: numeric || '
            AND bookingyear             = ' || bookingYearCol       :: numeric || '
            AND destinationbranchid     =  any (string_to_array(' || DestinationBranchIdCol ||',' || ',' || ')' :: numeric[] ||')';
```

Comment: Welcome to [dba.se]! Please explain how your query solves the author's problem; answers without explanation generally aren't received well.

Comment: this answer has nothing to do with the question. perhaps you've posted to the wrong page?