# Conditional WHERE in plpgsql function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.5

I'm writing function in plpgsql and stuck with following question: my function has parameter `service_id_input` and query. I want to create additional clause in WHERE section if this variable is not null. For example

```
SELECT
    MIN(time_from) AS min_0,
    MAX(time_to) AS max_0,
    CEIL((MAX(time_to) * 60 - MIN(time_from) * 60) / reception_duration_input) AS diff_0,
    user_id AS user_id_0,
    workingtimetable.date AS date_0
FROM
    workingtimetable
WHERE
    -- IF service_id_input is not null then add another restriction
    department_id = department_id_input AND date >= NOW() :: DATE
GROUP BY user_id, date
ORDER BY date ASC;
```

How can I do it?
Full code of function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_days_business(IN reception_duration_input INTEGER, IN department_id_input BIGINT, IN service_id_input BIGINT)
      RETURNS TABLE(avail_records NUMERIC, busy_records BIGINT, percentage NUMERIC, day_date DATE) AS
    $BODY$
    DECLARE
    BEGIN
      CREATE TEMP TABLE sum_of_avail_records ON COMMIT DROP AS
        SELECT
          SUM(diff_0) AS sum_0,
          date_0
        FROM (
               SELECT
                 MIN(time_from)                                                             AS min_0,
                 MAX(time_to)                                                               AS max_0,
                 CEIL((MAX(time_to) * 60 - MIN(time_from) * 60) / reception_duration_input) AS diff_0,
                 user_id                                                                    AS user_id_0,
                 workingtimetable.date                                                      AS date_0
               FROM workingtimetable
               WHERE
                 -- IF service_id_input is not null then add another restriction
                 department_id = department_id_input AND date >= NOW() :: DATE
               GROUP BY user_id, date
               ORDER BY date ASC
             ) AS perday
        GROUP BY date_0;

      CREATE TEMP TABLE num_of_busy_records ON COMMIT DROP AS
        SELECT
          COUNT(appointments_book_records.id) AS count_1,
          appointments_book_days.date         AS date_1
        FROM appointments_book_records
          INNER JOIN appointments_book_days ON appointments_book_records.appointment_day_id = appointments_book_days.id
        WHERE appointments_book_days.date >= NOW() :: DATE
        GROUP BY appointments_book_days.date
        ORDER BY appointments_book_days.date;

      RETURN QUERY
      SELECT
        sum_0,
        count_1,
        (count_1 / sum_0 * 100),
        date_0
      FROM sum_of_avail_records
        LEFT OUTER JOIN num_of_busy_records ON date_0 = date_1;
END;$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: `AND (service_id_input IS NULL OR (<another restriction>))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@Ypercube's comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/142948/conditional-where-in-plpgsql-function#comment271145_142948) answers your core question.

Your function is also slower and more complicated than necessary:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_days_business(_reception_duration int
                                            , _department_id bigint
                                            , _service_id bigint)
  RETURNS TABLE (avail_records numeric
               , busy_records bigint
               , percentage numeric
               , day_date date)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY
   SELECT s.sum_diff, n.ct, ((n.ct * 100) / s.sum_diff ), s.date
   FROM  (
      SELECT p.date, sum(p.diff) AS sum_diff
      FROM  (
         SELECT w.date
              , ceil(((max(w.time_to) - min(w.time_from)) * 60) / _reception_duration) AS diff
         FROM   workingtimetable w
         WHERE  w.date >= now()::date
         AND    w.department_id = _department_id
         -- another restriction IF _service_id is not null:
         AND   (_service_id IS NULL OR <another restriction>)
         GROUP  BY w.user_id, w.date
         ) p               -- perday
      GROUP  BY p.date
      ) s                  -- sum_of_avail_records
   LEFT   JOIN (
      SELECT d.date, count(*) AS ct
      FROM   appointments_book_records r
      JOIN   appointments_book_days    d ON r.appointment_day_id = d.id
      WHERE  d.date >= CURRENT_DATE
      GROUP  BY d.date
      ) n USING (date)        -- num_of_busy_records 
   ORDER  BY s.date;
END
$func$;
```

#### Major points

- Temporary tables are more expensive and not necessary here. Simple subqueries do the job.
- Don't include columns in the `SELECT` list that you don't need for anything. Dead weight. (You also don't need to include `GROUP BY` expressions in the `SELECT` list.)
- Don't `ORDER BY` in subqueries. While Postgres typically keeps the order in the outer `SELECT` for simple queries, this is completely arbitrary and not reliable. There is no provision in the SQL standard that would require propagation of `ORDER BY` in subqueries to the outer query.

If your are looking for **fully dynamic query predicates** or arbitrary dynamic query elements with optimized query plans, you'll have to use **dynamic SQL** and `EXECUTE`:

- [PostgresSQL dynamic execute with argument values in array](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83278/postgressql-dynamic-execute-with-argument-values-in-array/83536#83536)
- [Robust approach for building SQL queries programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25191127/939860)