# Is there a symbol I can use to have a where clause match all columns?

Tags: postgresql, parameter

I'm using sql parameter's and I have a query that I'd like to use for two similar queries. The first uses two where clauses the other uses only one of the clauses is there a symbol I can use for the second query to always equal true?

For example:

```
SELECT path, markdown
  FROM public."Comment"
  where path = 'relative/path/' AND markdown = 'here I am';
```

Second example:

```
SELECT path, markdown
  FROM public."Comment"
  where path = '/other/relative/path/' AND markdown = ALL;
```

`All` being a stand in for some symbol in the query that would make it effectively only search based on the path (because the markdown where clause would return true on all columns).

Comment: Is the `markdown` column nullable?

Comment: @MartinSmith no it is not

Comment: `where markdown = markdown` would work if it never contains `null` values

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I think they are passing in a parameterised string.

Comment: Can you change the query pattern? E.g. `where path = 'relative/path/' AND markdown Like 'here I am'`? Then you could just substitute `%` as the string literal. Though I don't know what the performance implications of doing that in Postgres are.

Comment: `I have a query that I'd like to use for two similar queries` .. why? It doesn't sound like they're similar enough, to me.

Comment: @MartinSmith: if you use `like` without a wildcard it will be the same as `=` performance wise

Comment: And by `sql parameter's` you mean prepared statements or an SQL function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not agree with the approach you are thinking of using, but if you are dead set on using it, then I would probably structure the query like this:

```
SELECT path, markdown
  FROM public."Comment"
  where path = '/other/relative/path/' AND (TRUE OR markdown = 'here I am');
```

Essentially adding a 3rd parameter to your query .. one use case would use the 3rd param and set the 2nd param to FALSE, while another would set the 2nd param to TRUE..

Comment: "I do not agree with the approach". Is this because of effect on the execution plans or some other reason?

Comment: Just that reusing SQL, unless it's for the exact same purpose, is bound to end up being messy and create coupling where it should not exist.  Having a query that gets "all comments where there is a path and a markdown" is a different use case than a query that gets "all comments where there is a path".

Comment: @JoishiBodio After thinking more about it I think you are right that the queries aren't similar enough to only use one query. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use this query instead:

```
SELECT path, markdown
FROM   public."Comment"
WHERE  path = $1
AND    ($2 IS NULL OR markdown = $2);
```

To ignore the second parameter, pass NULL for it.

Recent related question with more info:

- [Conditional WHERE in plpgsql function](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/142948/conditional-where-in-plpgsql-function/144058#144058)

Answer (score 1):

What language are you calling the query from?  I've used query builders to add additional criteria to a base query.   In this case, the query builder would add the check on markdown only if there was a value to compare it too.

The `AND markdown = ALL` conditional as you describe it is no different that if you had no `markdown` comparison in the `WHERE` clause.