# Filter a SELECT query with predicates passed as single hstore value

Tags: postgresql, dynamic-sql, plpgsql, hstore

For an API I am building I am supposed to write a function with a single `hstore` argument containing `colname => value` pairs so that queries may be filtered with a `WHERE` clause including an indefinite amount of subclauses. I currently have the following function definition (not a MWE):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION api.func( conds HSTORE )
RETURNS TABLE (LIKE api.tab) AS 
$$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
        SELECT * 
        FROM api.tab 
        WHERE -- conds here
        LIMIT 25 ;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I am not really sure how to continue. Could someone please give me a hint?

Comment: Hint: dynamic SQL.

Comment: @mustaccio: In the sense of building the `WHERE` clause as a string and then format it into the main query statement which I then run with `EXECUTE`?

Answer (score 0):

### Pure SQL

Can even be done with pure SQL and no function:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   api.tab t
WHERE  hstore(t.*) @> '"b"=>"bar", "a"=>2'  -- your hstore here
LIMIT  25;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/RvvDq5QT)

[`hstore(t.*)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/hstore.html#HSTORE-FUNC-TABLE) converts the whole row to hstore.
[`@>`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/hstore.html#HSTORE-OP-TABLE) is the hstore containment operator, which can be supported with a GIN or GiST index.

But this can only use an expression index on the whole row (which might get big and inefficient for wide rows):

```
CREATE INDEX tab_special_idx ON api.tab USING GIN (hstore(api.tab.*));
```

#### SQL function

The same in an SQL function wrapper:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION api.func(conds hstore)
  RETURNS SETOF api.tab
  LANGUAGE sql STRICT AS 
$func$
SELECT * 
FROM   api.tab t
WHERE  hstore(t.*) @> $1
LIMIT  25;
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM api.func('"b"=>"bar", "a"=>2');
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/RvvDq5QT)

#### PL/pgSQL with dynamic SQL

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION api.func(conds hstore)
  RETURNS SETOF api.tab
  LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT AS 
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE
      concat_ws(
        E'\n'
      , 'SELECT * FROM api.tab'
      , (SELECT 'WHERE ' || string_agg(format('%I = %L', key, value), ' AND ') FROM each($1))
      , 'LIMIT  25'
      );
END
$func$;
```

Same call.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/RvvDq5QT)

This can use any index as usual.

It's carefully drafted to be safe against SQL injection. Only adds a `WHERE` clause if there are filters.

Either of the functions is defined as `STRICT`, so returns NULL on NULL input.
An empty `hstore` input value returns the unfiltered table. `each()` produces no row, so no `WHERE` clause is added; `concat_ws()` concatenates NULL-safely.

Related:

- [How to use function parameters in dynamic SQL with EXECUTE?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/159424/how-to-use-function-parameters-in-dynamic-sql-with-execute/159534#159534)
- [PostgresSQL dynamic execute with argument values in array](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83278/postgressql-dynamic-execute-with-argument-values-in-array/83536#83536)